# Redirect to login page on ajax request

Tags: ajax, symfony

For authentication in my project I use 2 methods, form_login and Cas with a single Provider (user).
I set up login_form in security.yml and I created a Guard for Cas.
After many tests I managed to make the two authentications cohabit.
Now I start to put ajax in my pages and I am confronted with a new problem: all my ajax calls are redirected to the login page.
As all my ajax routes start with /api/, I tried to put in security.yml

```
- {path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

But I'm still redirected to the login page ...

I've look for an explanations since 3 days but I don't find yet.

my security.yml

```
   ...
   firewalls:
      dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false

    login_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/login$
        anonymous: true
    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: false
        form_login:
            provider: database
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            csrf_token_id: bien_authentifie
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: home
        logout:
             path:   caslogout
             target: https://xxx.xxxx.nnn/cas/logout
        switch_user: true
        guard:
             provider: database
             authenticators:
               - xxx.cas_authenticator


access_control:
  - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
  - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: According to this : `- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }`, all the paths of your application are behind a firewall. That's why your api calls redirect to login I think. Change it to `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` will likely solve the issue

Comment: yes but all my url for ajax start with /api/... and I have  - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } in access_control. That would be ok no ?

Comment: I just did a quick test on one of my applications and yes, if you put '/' behind a firewall, all your urls redirect to login page for authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your help but as you can check at http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html , for the use of access_control, as { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } is before { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER } it will be used when I call a /api/... url.    
I don't explain it in my question but I try to make an "intranet" so exept login form every thing will be behind the firewall. Actually I'm learning Ajax and even if it's not protected it's ok after I will need to protect it too.

Answer (score 1):

I've found :c)
It was so obvious, `anonymous: false` was the problem it has to be `anonymous: ~` for 
access_control work with IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY